# Salesforce Flow Converter

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

Does any kind of tool exist to display the full contents of a salesforce.com Flow in a single pseudo-code type page or, better still, to convert the Flow to Apex code?

Comment: Hi John, Welcome to SFSE! I am afraid not, no such tool to convert your flow to apex code. Probably to understand the Flow, you can see the visual components while you edit that flow or you can "Debug" that flow to understand what all steps involved in that flow. With that information you can write your apex class.

Comment: John, thanks for the idea! I wonder how difficult it would be to set up a rudimentary *.flow-meta.xml-to-Apex converter, e.g. in Javascript. This process has become a routine task these days, with Salesforce promoting flows and org complexity "unexpectedly" growing quickly.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of months late, but it took a while contemplating and setting this up, even if it is pretty basic: If you are still interested, have a look [here](https://www.steinwinde.com/flowex).

Answer (score 1):

I see you mention the *.flow-meta.xml so I guess you found out that you can access the 'source code' of flows.

I usually use VSCode for this, but you can also use workbench to download flow xmls. https://workbench.developerforce.com/